# Erro em sistema de busca com php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou criando um sistema de busca à usuários em meu site. No entanto estou enfrentando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código que estou utilizando:

```html
<body>
  <h2>Resultados da tua pesquisa</h2><br />
  <?php
   $query = $_GET['query'];

   $min_length = 3;

   if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) {
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE (`nome` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) {
     echo "<br /><br />";
     while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
      echo '<a href="perfil.php?id='.$results["id"].'" nome="p"><br /><p nome="p"><h3>'.$results["nome"].' '.$results["apelido"].'</h3></p><br /></a><br /><hr /><br />';
     }
    }else{
     echo "<br /><h3>Não foram encontrados resultados...</h3>";
    }
   }else{
    echo "<br /><h3>Tens de escrever pelo menos 3 letras...</h3>";
   }
  ?>
 </body>
```

O erro aponta a linha 17, que no caso, no trecho de código acima seria **linha 4**. Como posso resolver este erro e apresentar o resultado da busca corretamente?

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando capturar o índice que não existe. No caso `query` na variável `$_GET`.

Você pode fazer um ternário para verificar se o valor existe:

```
$query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : '';
```

Outra maneira seria usando `filter_input`.

```
$query = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'query');

if ($query !== false) {

    // minha lógica para consulta         

}
```

Comment: +1 É uma outra solução, mas nunca usei isso. Acredito que o `isset ()` pode servir melhor. :S

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `isset`.

Dessa forma utilize:

```
$min_length = 3;

if ( isset( $_GET['query'][ $min_length - 1 ] ) ) {

  // Seu código quando existe mais ou igual a 3 caracteres

}else{

  // Seu código quando não existe 3 caracteres    

}
```

O `isset` verifica "se existe", ou "se está definido", melhor dizendo.

Nesse caso ele verifica se o `$_GET['query'][2]` existe, ou seja se o terceiro caractere no `$_GET['query']`.

Isso é LIGEIRAMENTE mais rápido do que o `strlen`, pois ele apenas verifica se existe o terceiro caractere, não contando toda a string e então comparando. A diferença é MUITO PEQUENA e IMPERCEPTÍVEL, porém existe.

Você pode criar isso:

```
$min_length = 3;
$valido = isset( $_GET['query'][ $min_length - 1 ] );

if ( $valido ) {
//...
}else{
//...
}
```

Isso é exatamente a mesma função. ;)